# Google Analytics: Track third-party form submission embedded in iframe (with another iframe)

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I have a form hosted by a third party embedded on my site via an iframe (I'll call this the "Parent iFrame").  I would like to track those form submissions in Google Analytics.  If I embed another iframe (src being a page on my site that contains my site's GA code; I'll call this the "Child iFrame") within the Parent iFrame's form submission confirmation message, when the Child iFrame loads will that be recorded as a Pageview in Google Analytics?

*I researched this question and believe the answer is yes, but the answers I found were usually to more specific questions that didn't directly address this probably much more basic question.  Thanks for any help!*

I'm a little concerned about the iframe within an iframe situation, but I'm hoping that a visit within an iframe is simply tracked like any other page.  Just didn't want to assume... :)